# Stacking order with z-index

Tags: html, css

I have a stacking order problem with z-index. A few questions on SO actually deal with this issue but I am unable to resolve this issue despite reading a few in-depth articles on Z-index, [like this](http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex) one.

Now the issue I am facing is I have the following CSS:

```
.grey-box {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: 9999999;
}

.grey-box:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    background: #eee;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(45deg); /* Safari */
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    z-index: 2;    
} 

.grey-box:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    /*left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-top: -15px;*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

My issue is with the CSS not with HTML, so if you want to see the whole problem in action please refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/undmcszz/).

Now as you can see `.grey-box` is the container and I am using two pseudo-elements which are absolutely positioned. Now in spite of giving .grey-box a z-index of `z-index: 9999999` it still appears below .`grey-box:before` and `.grey-box:before` has a z-index of `z-index: -1`.

How do I solve this issue, how do I make `.grey-box` on top of `.grey-box:before`?

Comment: where you want to display this .grey-box

Comment: remove the z-index from parent ? http://jsfiddle.net/undmcszz/1/ position:relative; stacks it on top of static element without need of z-index :)

Comment: Maybe this is what you want? http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: @GCyrillus , i want the red line to be below `.grey-box` . the red line show be below it and not visible at all !

Comment: Did you understand the article you linked? The problem is that `.grey-box` creates a stacking context because of its `z-index`. Just remove it.

Comment: @Oriol if i remove the z-indx on grey-box , the red line still remans on top !

Comment: just do like for :after http://jsfiddle.net/undmcszz/3/ but where is he point to produce an absolute pseudo and hide it, it has no interaction within the flow this way :)

Comment: @GCyrillus sorry to bother you more , but can you describe what u've changed in that fiddle ?

Comment: z-index:1 to z-index:-1; but display:none; or not any :before pseudo would be as good :)

Comment: @GCyrillus thanks the objective was to have a shadow below the grey-box , like this http://jsfiddle.net/undmcszz/4/ , u have +25 if u add tat as an answer , with a couple of lines of explanation ! :)

Comment: now that you talk about a shadow, your objective sounds clear.You may Make an answer yourself with the explanation of your understanding of z-index , and collect some points ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75591/discussion-between-alexander-solonik-and-gcyrillus).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue is solved setting z-index to auto on the container

```
.grey-box {
    position: relative;
    padding: 50px 0;
    background: #eee;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

the pseudo element will reappear when its z-index is 0 or greater

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/undmcszz/7/)